# Manga from TikTok ad where protagonist seemed to have a physical disability, and her sister wanted to send her for marriage in her place

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I'm looking for the name of a full-color manga I recently got an ad for on TikTok.

The title was something along the lines of *Lady (name that I forgot ;;) is (a?) Something*.

It was a fantasy romance presumably, a lot of these manga were originally web novels so you might remember something like that with the same plot which would be helpful.

From the ad I think the protagonist had red or orange hair and her twin sister also had red or orange hair(?). Specifically, I think the twin had curly orange hair and sucked and the FL had straight red hair. I think they both had green eyes, and in the cover image the FL was holding a gun. The male lead had black hair.

The protagonist seemed to have a physical disability that her family bullied her for, and her sister wanted to send her for marriage in her place because she was dating a prince or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, were there any sci-fi or fantasy elements, such as reincarnation or magic? If not, then this question wouldn't be on-topic here.

Comment: Full color, I'm not sure if it was an Isekai or just Isekai vibes. Like I said it was an ad but I'm assuming it was a fantasy.

Comment: Could you go into more detail on what exactly was in the ad? You mention two girls, but are you certain they're twins? If she's getting married, did they show her new fiance at all (i.e. the probable male lead)?

Comment: It said they were twins, the male lead had black hair but thats all I know. The twin had curly orange hair and sucked and the fl had straight red hair. I think they both had green eyes, in the cover image she was holding a gun. I'm not too sure about my memory of the title though 

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: I guess the twin thing was a translation error of the ad ╮(. ❛ ᴗ ❛.)╭

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly *[All Hail Lady Blanche!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/all-hail-lady-blanche)*. It is licensed by Pocket Comics.

> To Blanche, everything seemed hopeless. Until she realized it was all a game. One she made, to be exact. Now she has a goal: Become the villain's right-hand man! But wait. Why is she the one saving him...?

Title includes "Lady", but not the rest of the structure. The elder sister has orange, curly hair:

[image: Curly]

And the protagonist has long, straight, red hair, and needs a cane:

[image: Straight red hair]

And the cover image shows the ML with the black-haired ML and the MC holding a gun:

[image: She's got a gun]

They do not appear to be twins, just sisters. However, the basic plot matches; Curly is trying to marry a prince and thus doesn't want to marry some old guy to escape her family's debt. So she suggests her sister do it instead.