# Manga/manhwa where the female protagonist reincarnates into a game that she made

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, webcomics

The female protagonist had red hair. She was a badass and super overpowered. She joined a gang and then became some sort of queen in the manhwa. I have been looking all over for it again.

They were trying to get through a dungeon called "Fiesta Dungeon," the last time I read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly *[All Hail Lady Blanche](https://www.pocketcomics.com/comic/7867)*

[image: Title image for All Hail Lady Blanche]

> To Blanche, everything seemed hopeless. Until she realized it was all a game. One she made, to be exact. Now she has a goal: Become the villain's right-hand man! But wait. Why is she the one saving him...?

From [this review of episode 34](https://www.theanimedaily.com/all-hail-lady-blanche-chapter-34-release-date/):

> Achille and his father Rodolfo planned to use an odorless portion of syncope to win over Blanche. She stalled their engagement and refused to marry Achille. But Rodolfo will work on a plan to have a word with her boss. He will indeed ask Blanche to think again, and she might get ready for the engagement to push Riccardo away. But she didn’t know Rodolfo and Achille were planning something vengeful against her.
>
> Meanwhile, she, Riccardo, Guillermo, and Mr. Silvano will work on executing their plan. They will head for the fiesta dungeon to extract the valuables. But it won’t be that easy for them. They will face some new challenges, and it will be tough for them to tackle them. But Mr. Silvano will help them to extract the valuables. Meanwhile, Rodolfo and his gang will join them and have an intense fight inside the dungeon before it collapses.

Found with a search for `manhua "fiesta dungeon"`

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262851/manga-from-tiktok-ad-where-protagonist-seemed-to-have-a-physical-disability-and/262936#262936